# getting list of languages supported by android keyboard

Tags: android, locale, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I need to display the list of the all languages which are supported by android keyboard. Now I am using `Locale.getAvailableLocales();` method but i am getting *language* and *country* constants.

I need all language names only. Is it possible? and how ?.

Comment: Have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [Locale.getDisplayName(Locale)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayName%28java.util.Locale%29) on each Locale you get with `Locale.getAvailableLocales();`?

> Returns this locale's language name, country name, and variant, localized to locale.
>
> new Locale("en").getDisplayName(Locale.US) -> English