# Find the language of the current Android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

how to find the language of the current keyboard in android in the code.
and how can I set the language of the keyboard in the code. for example if the user select Chinese the Chinese keyboard should appear and if select English the  English keyboard should appear .

Comment: One solution is that you write your own keyboard and inform it that you want a custom language and get it's current language. This is a little time consuming as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579046/getting-list-of-languages-supported-by-android-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of questions similar to this one that are already answered.
Most answers involve

`InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);`